# how to handle iframes using iOS webdriver, i am using iPhone 5s & 6S+? Kindly help me on this

Tags: ios, iframe

I am unable to do mouse and keyboard action in iPhone 5s and 6S+. Because of website contains iFrames. how to handle iframes in iOS (Mobile devices) ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If iFrames are present, you'll need to get their inner document to do mouse and keyboard actions. For UIWebView or WKWebView, this means adding 2 lines to the beginning of your script to insert into the webpage. Example:

```
NSString *scriptToInsert=@"var iFrame=document.getElementById('idOfFrame'); \
                           var innerDoc=iFrame.innerDocument || iFrame.contentWindow.document; \
                           //Now do other things w/ innerDoc instead of document
                             ";
```

Now, you would insert your script.

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:scriptToInsert];
```